# pynput краш потока без ошибки и бессмертный терминал

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

### Суть

День добрый. Столкнулся с проблемой в библиотеке pynput: в поток после вызова `pynput.mouse.Controller().scroll(dx, dy)` единожды выполняется прокрутка и сразу же все логи перестают приходить. Точки остановки в VS code полностью игнорирует. И сами не вылезают, и не удается поймать исключения. Сам скрипт остается бессмертным рухнувшим процессом. Ничем не получалось снять его (*про то, что сам терминал можно уничтожить я узнал после второй перезагрузки и двадцатого терминала xd*), хоть и показал только *Process Hacker 2*. *В действительности я в ступоре, так как второй день не понимаю этого поведения.*

---

### Задача

Подробней о том, что я пытаюсь сделать: эмуляция прокрутки колесика мыши слайдером подобно Blender'овскому слайдеру при изменении радиуса кисти в скульптинге. То есть оттягиваешь курсор по оси от центра слайдера, а он тебе прокручивает. Непонимающих прошу ознакомиться с графическими планшетами.

Не уверен, но вдруг кто захочет посмотреть мои наработки. Ошибка возникает в 75 строчке slider.py (`self.cnt.scroll(*offset)` (cnt - это pynput.mouse.Controller)). Возможно вам будет удобней иметь свои логи, поэтому предоставляю его *чистым* от logging.

---

*Мне больше интересно найти причину, по которой это случается, чем альтернативу. Спасибо за потраченое время.*

[Тут я показываю повтор проблемы, и слайдер размера кисти в Blender'е](https://youtu.be/ydSXjYIjMOA)

[Наработки кода с проблемой](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/5dcD/5sLEksEiW)

---

### Upd

Попробовал отладить события pynput. Для этого скопировал исходники библиотеки и добавил самописец логов о событиях прокрутки. В скриптах подменил библиотеку на модифицированную. В теории ошибка должна была остаться, но она исчезла. Еще больше мозг вынесло то, что программа работает с хоть каким то результатом только если pynput в файле listener.py был подключен из модифицированной библиотеки, а в slider.py из исходной библиотеки. Буквальный вынос мозга..

Comment: Мне кажется форк бомба

Comment: Совсем не то. Logger дает мне хорошее представление о том, что весь скрипт запускается единожды. На видео так много процессов потому, что до этого я раз 8 пытался выяснить в чем природа ошибки и конечно же оставались неуязвимые процессы самого скрипта.

Comment: Я не про форк бомбу как таковую. Смотри у тебя пайинпут генерит эвенты и слушает их. Может он генерит эвентов больше чем принимает и получается внутреннее зацикливание